# OMSA killed DRAC

Tags: centos, dell, dell-poweredge, drac, dell-openmanage

I used to be able to use both OMSA and DRAC at the same time on my PE1950. I've updated the OMSA recently and DRAC is not accessible right after starting "Systems Management Data Engine". Shutting down OMSA doesn't seem to start DRAC again.

Additional info:
DRAC NIC mode is on shared with its own IP

Appreciate any pointer to this issue.

Comment: Didn't realize this question was post almost a year ago. To update in case other people looking for answer, I never found out what was the problem. Since the server was replaced with a new server, it's no longer an issue. The new server has DRAC7 and I'm currently having issue with its license.

Answer (score 1):

pointer: call Dell techsupport, this sort of thing sounds like it should be a known issue

Comment: And prepare for the worst. Dell server support is horrible.

Comment: really? used to be the best 'bout 3-4 years ago

Comment: maybe the server is. I dealt with the support multiple times this month and it is the worst experience ever!